# Inject FragmentComponent dependencies to viewmodel with @ViewModelInject

Tags: android, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I want to use my `ViewModel` inside fragment with `FragmentComponent` dependencies but I think
`@ViewModelInject` provide ViewModel inside `ActivityComponent` or `ApplicationCoinmponent` and cant inject my `FragmentComponent` dependencies to `ViewModel`

```
class XViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val xClass: XClass // this dependency provides in FragmentComponent
) : ViewModel() {

}
```

When I trying to build the project. build failed with `KaptException` and the hilt compiler say I cant provide `XClass`. which `XClass` provide in `FragmentComonent`.
when I move the `XClass` provider method to `ActivityComponent` or `ApplicationComponent` build no more failed with `KaptException`.

Edit:
I read the generated code by Hilt and my guess was right, Hilt and `@ViewModelInject` Install `XViewModel` module in `ActivityRetainedComponent`. I have no idea why?

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityRetainedComponent.class)
@OriginatingElement(
    topLevelClass = XViewModel.class
)
public interface XViewModel_HiltModule
```

Comment: please add the error log to the question

Comment: Add class where you have provider for `XClass`. And your question's Title and description does not contain same problem . Pls make it clear

Comment: @AliSh hilt error: cant provide `XClass` without `@Inject` or provider method. but `XClass` provided in `FragmentComponent` and when I move `XClass` provider into `ActivityComponent` or `ApplicationComponent` everthing works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1939). hilt team does this because injecting things from the fragment component may leak Fragment instances across configuration changes.
`ActivityRetainedComponent` lives across configuration changes, so it is created at the first onCreate and last onDestroy